Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\cos\frac1x\right]^{h(x)}$, where $h(x)=\frac{x^4+x^2-1}{2x+1}\sin\frac1x$
I am struggling to calculate what $h(x)$ tends to in
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\right]^{h(x)}$$
where
$$h(x)=\dfrac{x^4+x^2-1}{2x+1}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$
This is a problem from a Calc $1$ Final.
I get to the part of  $\infty\cdot 0$, however I don't know where to follow from that. I tried L'Hôpital (it is allowed), but it just gets worse.
My attempt:


what is the sen?

@DannyBlozrov the sine function

@Nothingspecial the limit is to $\infty$

@SineoftheTime I've uploaded it! thx!

$\textbf{Hint:}$ For large $x$, we have that
$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sim 1 - \frac{1}{2x^2}$$
and
$$\frac{x^4+x^2-1}{2x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sim \frac{x^2}{2}$$
therefore your limit will be the same as
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
which is a familiar quantity.

If we let $u=x^2$, since $u\to +\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$, the limit is equivalent to $\lim_{u\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac1{2u}\right)^{\frac u2}$, which OP may recognize.

@ninadmunshi Thank you very much for your answer, however in class we don´t really use that approach, to be honest I've never seen a limit solved with those approximations!!

those are the taylor approximations for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ for $x\approx 0 $

We use Taylor but it's not something we are allowed to do for now with limits, we just have to use notable limits or l'hopital

@sofischh These don't have to be Taylor. Calculus I always covers linear and quadratic approximations which these are.

By substituting $t=1/x$ we get $t\to 0^+$ and
$$h(1/t)\log \cos t={1+t^2-t^4\over 2t^3+t^4}\sin t\log \cos t \  (*)\\
={1+t^2-t^4\over 2+t}{\sin t\over t}\,{\cos t -1\over t^2}\,{\log \cos t\over \cos t-1} \ (**)$$ The limit at $0$ of the first two ratios is equal $1/2.$ The limit of the last ratio, after substitution $u=\cos t$, is equal  to  $(\log u)'\big\lvert_{u=1}=1.$ The third ratio can be transformed to
$${\cos^2t-1\over t^2(\cos t+1)} =-\left ({\sin t\over t}\right )^2{1\over \cos t+1}\underset{t\to 0}{\longrightarrow}-{1\over 2}$$ Summarizing the limit at $0$ of the expression in $(*)$ is equal $-1/4.$ Applying the exponential function in $(*)$ we get the limit  $e^{-1/4}.$
Remark The tools applied in the answer are: $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}{\sin t\over t}=1,$ $(\log u)'\big\lvert_{u=1}=1$ and the continuity of the exponential function $v\to e^v$ ($v$ denotes the expression in $(*)$). The last two ratios in $(**)$ can be represented as ${\log\cos t\over t^2}.$ Then the l'Hopital rule gives $$\lim_{t\to 0}{\log\cos t\over t^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}{-\sin t\over 2t\cos t}=-{1\over 2}$$

I found this cool inequality and never managed to used it before, so here it goes: $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}2) \implies \frac{\sin(x)}{x} > \frac 2{\pi}$
of course for $x > \frac 2{\pi}$ we will have $0 < \frac1x < \frac{\pi}2$ so:
$$\sin(\frac1x) > \frac 2{x\pi}$$
we are done:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}h(x) > \frac 2{\pi} \frac{x^4+x^2-1}{2x^2+x} \to \infty$$
with $\in(x) < x$ you can guarantee it goes on $\mathcal O(n^2)$
